# How do I add the sum of two inputs?

Tags: python

Hello everyone I am very new to Python I am taking a beginner course at my college, and I am stuck on one portion of my project. Basically the goal of my code is to produce the output so that when I enter any age and name the result is supposed to find the sum of the age and number of letters in the entered name. So far this what I have typed up.

```py
print('What is your name?')    
myName = input()

print('What is your age?')  
myAge = input()

sum = myAge + str(len(myName))

print(myName + ', if we add the number of letters in your name to your age then you will be ' + sum + ' in ' + str(len(myName)) + ' years.')
```

When I run the script all I get is the age+length of name which gives me a combination and not a sum. example 21 + 4 = 214.

Basically my issue with this is that I don't understand how to find the sum of both inputs so that I get result of adding age and the length of letters in a name. The last portion that I am trying write should in other words be this "Name, if we add the number of letters in your name to your age then you will be # in # years."

If anyone can explain to me how I can accomplish this then I would greatly appreciate it I have spent hours looking into this issue but can't figure it out.

Comment: I recommend you this page for tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/python/

Answer (score 2):

When you use `input()` it returns a string. 
So when setting it to sum, you end up with "21" + "4" (which will result in a string) -> "214"

Try converting myAge to an int like so

```py
sum = int(myAge) + len(myName)
```

This will make it where you add 21 + 4 (now both numbers), so you'll get 25

Comment: this should be `sum = int(myAge) + len(myName)`, you can't add a str to an int

Comment: There is no casting in python. I think you mean a conversion from string to int. However, have you run your code?

Comment: whoops good catch @nik, edited the post to reflect that

Comment: the int function should be declared in myAge = int(input())

Answer (score 0):

Result of "***input()***" always is a string. You need to convert your input to integer using:

```
myAge = int(input('What is your age?'))
```

Answer (score 0):

During the sum of the two variables should be converted to integers or decimals

```
print('What is your name?')
myName = input()

print('What is your age?')
myAge = input()

sum = float(myAge) + float((len(myName)))

print(myName + ', if we add the number of letters in your name to your age then you will be ' + str(sum) + ' in ' + str(len(myName)) + ' years.')
```

[image]